# Dynamically change language in liferay

Tags: liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-velocity

Following is my requirement:

I need to change language dynamically. So I have one button which will have toggle values.
So when value is "English" it will show content in english and when value is something else say "Hindi" then it will show content in Hindi.

Is there any way to achieve this functionality dynamically?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you check languages portlet that comes with liferay?

Answer (score 4):

- You can change with inbuilt language portlet. For Hindi language you
  can set below locales properties in portal-ext.properties.  You add
  remove required supported locale.The Hindi locale beta version
  available after 6 liferay version.

  locales.enabled=hi_IN,ar_SA,ca_AD,ca_ES,zh_CN,zh_TW,cs_CZ,nl_NL,en_US,fi_FI,fr_FR,de_DE,el_GR,hu_HU,it_IT,ja_JP,ko_KR,nb_NO,fa_IR,pl_PL,pt_BR,pt_PT,ru_RU,es_ES,sv_SE,tr_TR,vi_VN

  http://www.liferay.com/web/manish.gupta/blog/-/blogs/new-feature-in-liferay-6-0-hindi-language-translation

  To add it in the your custom theme use below code.

  $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue("portletSetupShowBorders", "false")
  $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue("languageIds", "pt_BR,en_US,hi_IN")
  $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue("displayStyle", "1")
  $theme.runtime("82", "", $velocityPortletPreferences.toString())
  $velocityPortletPreferences.reset()

Answer (score 0):

you can switch using liferay urls.

if the language is english you can use localhost:8080/en/...

if the language is other you can use localhost:8080//...